# accessing elements of a lift-json parsed object in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, list, parsing, lift-json

I have parsed a json using lift-json parser in scala.I did this to parse the json object:

```
var parsedstring =parse(x)
```

The class of "parsedstring" is `net.liftweb.json.JsonAST$JObject` Then I did this:

```
var parsedmap = (parsedstring.asInstanceOf[JObject].values)
```

The class of "parsedmap" is `scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1`
then i did this:

```
var parsedactors = parsedmap("actors")
```

"actors" is key in parsedmap. 
Tha class of parsedactors is this:
`scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon`
I have to access elements of parsedactors. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

`scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon` means it's a list, so you can access it e.g. via

```
val list = parsedmap("actors")
val first = list(0)
val second = list(1)
```

etc. Or you can map over it, use it in a for-comprehension, etc.

Comment: I had given it a try. It did not work. This is the output of parsedactors(1):
scala:63: Any does not take parameters
[error]                println(parsedactors(1))

Comment: you can find solution in this link: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10046.html